# Gitlab runner installed on Kubernetes is not showing up in Gitlab UI when trying to set up runner

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have followed the instructions on this page about setting up a Gitlab runner on a Kubernetes cluster. Run GitLab Runner on a Kubernetes cluster

I have already registered a cluster to the group by going to Operation -> Kubernetes and also created the Gitlab namespace on the Kubernetes cluster. I have followed steps 1 to 4 and still cannot see the runner in the group settings by going [Settings -> CI/CD -> Runners -> Group Runners]

Here is what I have in the runner_config.yml file, for the token field, **I used the registration token provided by the Gitlab UI**. it is provided at Settings -> CI/CD -> Runners -> Group Runners:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: gitlab-runner
  namespace: gitlab
data:
  config.toml: |
    concurrent = 10



[[runners]]
  name = "Kubernetes Runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.com"
  token = "<REDACTED>"
  executor = "kubernetes"
  [runners.kubernetes]
    namespace = "gitlab"
    image = "ubuntu:18.04"
```

I kept the runner_deployment.yml file the same as is.

I have checked the status of the of the pod in Kubernetes and it is running as expected. But when I try to go and set up the group runner in Gitlab, I cannot see it. I’m expecting to see it because the instructions state that I should be able to.

**"The new runner will now show up in the GitLab web UI at the appropriate level (instance, group or project)."**

Comment: Are you sure the runner can access the gitlab server?

Comment: if you are admin of your Gitlab, do you see the runner in the Admin Area > Overview > Runners ?

Comment: @NicolasPepinster Yes, I am the owner of the gitlab repo. Just to give more information. I'm using the cloud based version of Gitlab and I have my own kubernetes cluster on AWS. Is this where my issue lies?

Comment: Does the namespace `gitlab` has the proper RBAC?

Comment: You forgot to add the link to the instructions page. Could you please add it?